# Is there a way to hide a layer from the LayerSwitcher (OpenLayers) but still see the corresponding GeoExt.LegendPanel?

Tags: openlayers, show-hide, layer, legend, geoext

I have a legend from my map layers. It's adding a color legend for each layer added dynamically.

**My problem : When I ask the layer to be hidden in the layer switcher (I don't want to see it there) it's not showing me the legend anymore, even if the layer is visible.**

Is there a way that I can keep it out of the layerSwitcher while letting my legend on display? I want to bypass the problem the libray is causing me. If there was a way to hide the layer from the LayerSwitcher of OpenLayers WITHOUT using DisplayInLayerSwitcher: false, it would solve my problem!!!

This is the code of my legend:

```
//------ Legend Window ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*              --> LegendPanel (This GeoExt Panel automatically displays the legend image of the layer if the layer has been added to the map.
 *                                      If this paticular layer has been removed from the map, his legend image will also automatically be removed from the GeoExt Panel.)
 */
function createLegendPanel(){
        return new Ext.Window({
                id: 'legend_panel_extjs',
                header: true,
                title: '<center>' + extjs_gui_east_panel_title + '</center>',

                shadow: false,
                closable:false,

                collapsible: true,
                animCollapse: false,
                cls: 'WindowPanelCls',
                resizable: false,
                //resizeHandles: 'w',
                draggable: false,

                width:(legendMaxWidth+17),
                height:(legendMaxHeight+15),
                plain: true,

                listeners: {
                        show: windowPosition,
                        collapse: windowPosition
                },
                items: [
                        new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
                                id:'extjs_gui_legend_panel_list',
                                map: map,
                                region:'west',
                                layout: 'table',

                                filter: function(record){
                                        if( !(record.getLayer().isBaseLayer) && !(record.getLayer() instanceof OpenLayers.Layer.Vector) ){
                                                return true;
                                        }
                                },

                                defaults: {
                                        showTitle: false,
                                        baseParams: {
                                                format: 'image/png',
                                                lang: lang
                                        }
                                        ,style: '{border-style: ridge;}'
                                }
                        })
                ]
        });
}
```

Thanks all.

PS: From the GeoExt website:
*The LegendPanel will include legends for all the layers in the layerStore it is configured with, **unless the layer is configured with displayInLayerSwitcher: false**, or a layer record has a hideInLegend field with a value of true. Additional filtering can be done by configuring a filter on the LegendPanel.*